# In SSRS: If table is larger than the available area on a page, then the entire table should start in the next page

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reporting

In SSRS usually if the table is larger than the page and not able to fit in one page, then it spreads to the next page. But in my case I want to have the entire table in one single page, instead of breaking the table across multiple pages.

I tried with Rectangle container and also tried providing height of the SSRS Report to 0 inches, but still no luck.

Is this possible to do in SSRS, if yes need some help to know how to do...

Answer (score 0):

Go into Tablix properties and check "Keep together on one page if possible"

Make report height 0 too.